# How to rename duplicate rows

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, worksheet-function

I have an Excel sheet with I have around 25k rows of data in the following format:

**Column1 | Column 2**

```
A | value1    
A | value2    
A | value3    
B | value1    
B | value2    
C | value1    
C | value2
```

and so on. I would like to rename the duplicate rows and put an integer in place of it. I would like the new data to be:

**Column1 | Column 2**

```
  1 | value1    
  1 | value2    
  1 | value3    
  2 | value1    
  2 | value2    
  3 | value1    
  3 | value2
```

How can this be done?

Comment: what do you mean when you say duplicate row? Duplicate by column1?

Comment: If you're looking for a programming solution - then you may wish to state so. Otherwise, if you're after just using the features in Excel, then this question is better asked on superuser

Comment: @Konstant yes duplicate by Column1

Comment: @JonClements no im looking for excel related ways only. like some scripts or macros. and link to superuser?

Comment: @pnuts oh sorry about that, The second sheet "Specifications", i'm only concerned about the first column, "Item Name"

Comment: @pnuts Im sorry about that, not the first Category, but yes I want the contents of the Second column (named "Item Name") to be manipulated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im assuming your Column 1 is in Col A and your Column 2 is in Col B and that you just simply want to convert letters (capital letters) to number.

Insert a new column as Col A. So now your letter are in Col B. Then type the formula

```
=CODE(B2) - 64
```

in cell A2 (assuming row 1 is for headings) and drag it down.

Then copy the whole of Col A, right click on cell A1 and choose paste values. Then delete Col B.

---

Based on your comment do the following instead.

Insert a column between the two in you example. In the top cell of the column put the value `1`. In the next cell `=IF(A2<>A1,B1+1, B1)` and then drag down.

[image]

Comment: Apart from pnuts comment, this won't take care of column values beyond Z. For values like AA, this would be incorrect

Comment: hi all, the values in Column1 are not what i have given here, these were just an example, the actual values are something like "Samsung Focus" , "Nokia Lumia" etc...

Comment: @Konstant true but the OP did not mention such a case. For the screen shot provided this works.

Comment: @dan sorry for the confusion, i have updated the question with the link of the excel file.

Comment: @Monodeep sorry can't download that, but does my second solution not work for you? Are your categories (phone names) not in blocks? Will it always be A A A B B C C or can it be A A B A B C C?

Comment: @dan my phone names are normal words and not necessarily in blocks, for example : `Huawei G5510, Huawei Smartphone U8800 Ideos X5, LG Optimus Sol E730`

Comment: By blocks I mean can Huawei G5510 appear in between a bunch of LG Optimus Sol E730s?

Comment: @pnuts I'm not following you I'm afraid...? I have neither downvoted anyone nor received downvotes in this post?

Comment: @dan yes i misunderstood your point, yes the names will always be in blocks, the phone names will exist in blocks, other phone name will not appear in between a block.

Comment: @Monodeep so then my =IF(A2<>A1,B1+1, B1) formula must surely work? Have you tested it?

Comment: okay i've found what i was doing wrong, it was the cells not properly being referenced. Thanks everybdy

Answer (score 3):

Given the confusion, an alternative which I cannot describe in detail because of the ambiguity of the question, in outline is:

Copy ‘Column1’ to a new sheet (when might as well sort alphabetically). Remove Duplicates. Index result and use new sheet as a lookup table.

EDIT (to provide some details now that clarification has been provided):

Copy `ColumnB` of Sheet `Specifications` to a new book as `ColumnA`.
Name tab `Table`.
Unmerge cells.
Sort alphabetically.
Select `ColumnA`, Data Tools, Remove Duplicates.
Select first visibly unoccupied row, `Ctrl+Shift+Down`, Delete.
Save workbook as Table.xls. Close and reopen `Table.xls`.
Key: in `A1` `Item#`; in A2 `1`; in `A3` `=A2+1`.
Double click bottom RH corner of `A2`.
Copy `ColumnA` to `ColumnC`.
In `Specifications` insert a column on the far left.
Key: in `A1` `Item#`; in `A2` `=VLOOKUP(C2,Table.xls!$B:$C,2,FALSE)`
Double click bottom RH corner.
Manually adjust `#N/A` results (merged cells).

Can move `Table` into same workbook if desired.

Comment: If it is not the case that all phones with the same names appear in consecutive rows, then this is the way to go. Otherwise use the IF formula I have provided.

Comment: @pnuts thanks, i was also thinking something similar, but im afraid i don't know how to use the sheet as lookup table. I'll do some Googling on that, and if possible, could you point me in that direction with some articles or anything ? Thanks

Comment: @dan i have consecutive blocks only. I have tried your approach but i am getting some weird results. Might be i am doing something wrong here. But For the first block of values i am getting "1" and as soon as the second block comes, the values alternated between "1" and "2"

Comment: @dan http://www.sendspace.com/file/ao7ijn here is a screenshot of my results with our approach